# Какой генератор можно использовать для вставки в строку?

Tags: python

Есть таблица Treeview() и есть список кортежей, каждый из которых нужно вставить в таблицу

```
# Напрмер, таблица имеет 4 столбца. Кортеж - 4 элемента
    table = Treeview(...)
for i in rowlist: 
    table.insert("", END, values=(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]))

#Этим способом все отлично вставляется, но если таблица большая, 
#то каждый элемент вписывать очень накладно. Пробуем вставить генератор

table = Treeview(...)
for i in rowlist: 
    table.insert("", END, values=((i[j] for j in range(len(i)))))
```

В результате, в первый столбец каждой строки вставляется `<generator object...` в общем генератор вставляется как объект, а не как сгенерированные значения. 
Как бы его заставить генерировать `i[0], i[1] ... i[20]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вообще переводить из кортежа в кортеж?
Простейший код должен работать:

```
table = Treeview(...)
for row in rowlist:
  table.insert("", END, values=row)
```

Ежели хочешь быть уверенным, что в параметр values попадает значение с типом кортеж, то так явно и напиши: `values=tuple(row)`

Comment: Упс.. И правда. Делать из кортежа кортеж, чтоб вставить. Заработался чутка.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте tuple

```
values = tuple(i[j] for j in range(len(i)))
table.insert("", END, values=values)
```